# "node not active but active node not found" - Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to implement a custom Vault HTTP client in Go. I've successfully managed to unseal the Vault. However, when I'm trying to enable AppRole I get the following error message in the HTTP response:

`{"errors":["node not active but active node not found"]}`

The related snippet of code is:

```
appRoleUrl := BASE_VAULT_URL + "sys/auth/approle"
// enable app role
_request := gorequest.New()
if _, body, errs := _request.Post(appRoleUrl).
    Set("X-Vault-Token", rootToken).
    Send(`{"type":"approle"}`).End(); hasErrs(errs) {
    return errors.New(stringifyErrs(errs))
} else {
    fmt.Println("enableAppRoleWithPolicy", body) // error here
    return createACLPolicy(rootToken)
}
```

The URL and the root token is correct! What am I missing?

Comment: I also see this error if I try to immediately login when a cluster is up with the CLI.  If I wait, it goes away.

Comment: Hi, Did you find any fix for the above issue ?